# context menu windows 10

Tags: windows, context-menu

How can I add some program to the Context Menu for a specific file type like `.mp4`.

I just need to add Player app just for specific file type with Icon, font style like Bold and Italic like above image.

[image]

Comment: How about right click a file, then click "open with" ? If "open with" is missing then google for that, there are many pages about it e.g. https://www.howtogeek.com/261076/how-to-fix-the-missing-open-with-option-on-the-windows-10-right-click-context-menu/

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, open with it's easy, I know it. But I need to do what I asked. Thanks again.

Comment: The context menu is a right click menu, so how is what you are asking about different to 'open with'?  (note- some people have voted to close your question perhaps because they think it is unclear what you are asking)

Comment: it is completely unclear what the author wants. Clarify the question

Comment: Sorry about my English that is why my question was unclear.

Comment: Is your question how to add an entry on the context menu *that appears in bolded italics*?

Comment: Yeah! That is correct.